# XCOM Operator with SnowflakeOperator

Tags: airflow

Using a SnowflakeOperator with an SQL that has been templated. My SQL Query is as follows

```
SELECT
  *
FROM MY_TEST_TABLE
WHERE MD_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP >='{{ params.par_date }}'
```

Calling this code from an SnowflakeOperator as

```
    snowflake_select = SnowflakeOperator(task_id="snowflake_select", sql="/queries/query.sql", params={'par_date': "{{ti.xcom_pull(key=\'PAR_DATE\')}}"}, snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn", )
```

The XCOM is been pushed in a upstream Function. Is it possible to do what I am doing ?

Answer (score 0):

`params` is not templated field so you can not use Jinja strings with it.
In your case there is no need to use `params` at all. Just use `xcom_pull` directly in the SQL:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM MY_TEST_TABLE
WHERE MD_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP >='{{ti.xcom_pull(key='PAR_DATE')}}'
```

and the Operator:

```
snowflake_select = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id="snowflake_select",
    sql="/queries/query.sql",
    snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn"
)
```